# using typekit in a mail chimp template

Tags: email, mailchimp, webfonts, typekit

i'm trying to use a webfont from typekit in mail chimp but the font isn't holding once the email is sent. right now I'm doing it like this

```
<head>
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/gge4dxp.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

</head>

.tagline {
    font-family: proxima nova;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align:center;
}
```

any ideas? i've looked around and it seems sometimes the head gets stripped out? is there a more sure way to embed this font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web fonts are barely supported in email clients. The only places that it is really supported is Apple Mail, iOS, some native Android clients and Thunderbird.  Everywhere else just strips the tags. If you know the majority of your subscribers use these email clients, then you should have no issue, but for all others, it may not be worth the font stacking effort.

The other issue you are having is that there are 0 email clients that will accept ANY javascript. This is a security issue, so to stave off any potential threat they wipe it all away.

The only way to bring in a webfont is via @import, via @font-face or `<link>`.`<link>` has the best support, but as I said above, all have meager support.  For more detailed info on webfonts in email, visit: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/

For typography tips see: https://litmus.com/blog/typography-tips-for-email-designers